# What technique is used to create these image based icons?

Tags: icon, images

I just saw a mailbox zero inbox icon and thought it was cool! I am wondering: what is the technique to create this artwork?

Mask with an image? I am looking for a keyword to google it.

Example:

[image: http://24.media.tumblr.com/2b4d82d6e95c5671300a1d1098e2f0e4/tumblr_mh2dm46sdd1qz4gu8o1_500.png]

Comment: "photoshop, mask, image, _vector_" might give more results. e.g.: http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-add-a-vector-mask-to-a-layer-in-photoshop-c.html

Answer (score 3):

It is merely an **image layer** with a **layer mask** applied. The layer mask is determining the overall shape.

[image: mask]